# Extends simple getter, setter Methods for Classes in C#

Tags: c#, class, extend, setter, getter

I have a abstract class 'Building':

```
public abstract class Building {
abstract public int ID {get;}
abstract public string name {get;}
}
```

the class (for example) Headquarter : Building has the Variables for these getter and setter methods. The Problem is I have to write in every Subclass

```
private int _ID = 1;
public int ID {
    get {return _ID;}
}
```

Is there a way to create for example one getter setter method like ahead, in the abstract class and save the code, so that I only have to set the variables?
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of making the properties abstract, you could make the setter protected, and/or allow them to be set in the constructor:

```
public abstract class Building 
{
    // Optional constructor
    protected Building(int id, string name)
    {
         this.ID = id;
         this.Name = name;
    }

    public int ID { get; protected set; }
    public string Name { get; protected set; }
}
```

This moves the implementation into the base class, but still only allows the subclasses to set those values.

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding a `protected` setter in base class and set the value in ctor of derived classes:

```
public class Building
{
     public int Id{get;protected set;}
```

and in derived class:

```
public class Headquarter: Building
{
    public Headquarter()
    {
        Id = 1;
    }
}
```